# How to get inputs from my view to my controller - SPRING JAVA JPA THYMELEAF

Tags: java, spring, maven, thymeleaf

I'm developing a webApp in java, maven, JPA and thymeleaf and I have this problem:

I have this method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/searchResults", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listResults(@ModelAttribute Step step,Model model,@PathVariable("dateStart") Date dateStart,@PathVariable("dateEnd") Date dateEnd){

    model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateStart);
    model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateEnd);
    return "thisAreTheDates";
}
```

And this is a fragment of the view that in theory has to send the 2 date parameters to my fancy controller:

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline" data-th-action="@{/admin/searchResults}" method="get" >
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>From:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateStart"  class="form-control"/>
                    <label>To:</label>
                    <input type="date" id = "dateEnd"  class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Generate Report</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Everything goes so good, until I go to that view, fill the fields with 2 dates and when I press the button of generate report, this error appears:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun May 28 10:54:07 BOT 2017
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Missing URI template variable 'dateStart' for method parameter of type Date

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you need to add `name="dateStart"` and `name="dateEnd"` to each of your `dateStart` and `dateEnd` input fields, respectively.  This will allow your form connect to your model attribute.

Additionally, you will want to add a method to your controller annotated with  `@PostMapping` to actually handle what you want to be done with your form input.

Finally, you will not want to use `get` on your HTML `form` but more likely, `post`.

So:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/searchResults") //use the shorthand
public String listResults(@ModelAttribute("step") Step step,
                          @PathVariable("dateStart") Date dateStart,
                          @PathVariable("dateEnd") Date dateEnd,
                          Model model) {
    Step step = new Step();  //or however you are creating this
    model.addAttribute("step", step);
    model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateStart);
    model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateEnd);
    return "thisAreTheDates";
}
```

Your Post Mapping:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/searchResults") //use the shorthand
public String postResults(@ModelAttribute("step") Step step, 
                          Errors result) {

    //validate your step bean
    someValidator.validate(step, result);

    //persist it, do whatever
    someService.save(step);

    return "confirmationPage";
}
```

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <form class="form-inline" th:object="${step}" th:action="@{/admin/searchResults}" method="post" >
         <div class="input-group">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label>From:</label>
                 <input type="date" name="dateStart" id="dateStart"  class="form-control"/>
                 <label>To:</label>
                 <input type="date" name="dateEnd" id="dateEnd" class="form-control"/>
             </div>
         </div>
         <br/>
         <button type="submit" class="button">Generate Report</button>
     </form>
</div>
```